# VideoJS Dash Widevine modular DRM return function

Tags: javascript, video.js

How to catch and manipulate "second license" by license 1?

I don't understand that tutorial in Github.

```
var player = videojs('video', options, function onPlayerReady() {
    player.src({
        src: 'ggg.com/asd.mpd',
        type: 'application/dash+xml',
        keySystemOptions: [{
            name: 'com.widevine.alpha',
            options: {
                serverURL: 'http://example.com/lisence1.php'
            }
        }]
    });

    setInterval(function(toisto) {
        player.play();
    },2000);
});
```

So I need to add code below to above but how? Code above works fine but I need to manipulate DRM key with another license server.

```
var updateSourceData = function(source) {
    source.keySystemOptions = [{
        name: 'com.widevine.alpha',
        options: {
            serverURL:'https://example.com/anotherlicense'
        }
    }];
    return source;
};

videojs.Html5DashJS.hook('updatesource', updateSourceData);
```

https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-dash